# Can I change the attributes of a directory from a failed mirror that is showing as a file back to a directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, corruption

I had a raid mirror fail and I was able to bring back up one of the drives after I replaced a bad HBA and copy everything to another system. I had a backups directory on this mirror that is now showing as a file. I know when the HBA failed and the directory should contain data from before that failure. But it looks like the attributes at the file system level have corrupted. Is there any way I can change them back to list it as a directory?

ls -l shows

`-rw-rw-r--.  1 userA userA 6163115952 Jan 17  2022 backups`

file shows

`backups: data`

Distro is AlmaLinux release 8.6 (Sky Tiger)

Comment: No. The only thing you can do is delete it and recreate it as a directory. (Well of course you could open the disk partition in a hex editor and flip the bits directly to change it, the point is there are no system calls to do what you want).

Comment: Any pointers on how what to change with a hex editor? I actually did some searches for exactly that. Edit: I have used hex editors for years on win PCs and DOS. But I never have had to do it in linux.

Comment: The information of the filetype is kept in the inode. Using "ls -li" will list the inode number. The inodes are usually distributed across the disk in blocks, so there might be the first 200 inodes, then 4000 data blocks, then 200 inodes, then 4000 data blocks, and so on. The layout will vary with different file systems. So if the inode number is 410, and the layout is as I describe you would want the 10th entry of the 3rd group. If each inode is 128 bytes in size then the 200 inodes would take 128*200 = 24k. So a group would take (128*200+4000*4096) bytes....

Comment: You would want the data at 2*(128*200+4000*4096)+10*128. Are you sure that the "file" actually looks like a directory?

Comment: A "file" that is 6GB long is not likely to be a directory. It is much more likely to be either a particular file or some kind of archive of multiple files. Did you run fsck of the filesystem. This would probably have put files missing their containing directory into the "lost+found" directroy at the top of the filesystem. Can you add details about what filesystem you are using (ext4, btrfs, ...) to the question.